# vim problem when in "try" ... "catch" an "if" is between

Tags: vimscript

When a vim script is to be watched for errors and interrupts, `try` is put somewhere near the beginning and `catch` after a long sequence of code. In this sequence of code it is very probable to have some condition commands, *i.e.*, `if … endif`, etc. Now when I type `CTRL-C` or an error occurs, this happens randomly with respect to the location in code, *e.g.*, after `if` and before `endif`. Thus it is natural that `catch` gives the error message, *i.e.*, `missing :endif` and terminates the script.

How can I handle this situation in vim?

Comment: This is not how things should work. If Ctrl-C is received while Vim is executing a statement inside an `if..endif` block program execution jumps to the `catch` section (I'm assuming `catch` is "bare" so it catches all errors). You definitely shouldn't get a `missing :endif` error. You should double check your code to make sure you don't have any actual syntax type errors.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my code is not bad, repeated and written in various way 5 days long. even silent, "silent! catch" does not help, error message persists and crash persists, the echo command following catch is not executed, insted the script (from souced file) is terminated unnormall.

Comment: Then it'll be best if you post the code if possible...see if anyone else can reproduce the issue. (If it's too big try to reduce it to a smaller sample that still reproduces the problem.)

Comment: There was a bug on the mailing list recently about try and if, but I don’t recall the details.

Comment: According to your advice I have prepared a demo code. Since I do not know how to send a file, I tried to insert it to here, but your message is: 455 charactrts left.

Comment: Don't add your code to a comment. Hit [Edit](https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/34799/edit) to update your question and paste in the code. Put three backticks alone on the line before the code and the line after the code so it's formatted.